# Looking for a String keyed map with efficient lookup and disk persistence

Tags: java, performance, lucene

I have a data structure which will have Strings as the key referencing an integral value.  I cannot fit all the String keys into memory.  My most important focus is to perform fast lookups.  If I were going to implement this myself (with no tools or libraries), I was thinking of implementing a b-tree where the nodes are the utf-8 byte value of the string.  The depth would correspond to the position in the string.  At some point, though, the tree would need to be persisted on disk because the whole thing won't fit into memory.  I can imagine many optimizations to this that I won't have time to write.  Before I get started, I was wondering if there's already any tools out there like this?  Perhaps lucene might do the trick, but I'm not sure since I need exact matching (not fuzzy).  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a database? They are quite good at this sort of thing, and have all this B-tree logic you refer to built in via indexes?

Comment: How about mimicking `HashMap<String, int>` in some way that uses disk storage; or even better, just use the plain hashmap and let the VM deal with the paging?

Comment: You could combine elements of a disk based b tree and a trie to get really space-efficient indexing algorithm. Or take a look at Berkeley DB for an invented wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Redis](http://redis.io/).It provides persistent data-structures.

Answer (score 1):

See [HTree](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/V1.0/doc/api/) or [BTree](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/V1.0/doc/api/) from the [JDBM](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/) project.

They don't implement the `Map` interface but offer similar API's.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is too easy - why don't you use a hashing strategy like md5 or sha1?  Obviously the time to do the hashing will factor in and this wouldn't solve your problem if you need to know the actual string value, but perhaps you don't.